# Skip around on same page using input

Tags: input

How can I use the html input command to skip around on the same web page? If use "a NAME="4" /A", how can I input a 4 and make it go to 4?

I know just about nothing, so if there is an easier way for a newbie, please tell me. What I want is for the user to be able to input a number to skip around on the same page. The page is huge, about 50 pages of actual reading.

Comment: so what did you try?

Comment: <form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank"> <p>Go to page: <input type="number" name="page"> <input type="submit" value="Go!"></p> </form>      I just copied this and I get the input but don't know how it works or what to do with it.

Comment: I want the viewer to be asked to submit the page number to which he wants to go, and then be taken there.